# Is MMSE decreasing function of variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

suppose we have two independent r.v. $Z$(standard-normal) and $X$(any r.v.) with $E[X^2]=\sigma^2$.
Let 
\begin{align*}
Y=X+Z
\end{align*}

My question is MMSE given by
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E[X|Y])^2]
\end{align*}

is it a decreasing( or non-increasing) function of $\sigma^2$?

My intuition tells me is that if we increase $\sigma^2$ then MMSE should decrease. 
But how to show it formally?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I cannot be decreasing.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören  why not?

Comment: Because you reach the minimum MMSE when $\sigma\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Yes. You right, but it is also not increasing in $\sigma$. Since, increasing $\sigma$ can result in batter estimation. Right?

Comment: I cannot guarantee whether it is increasing or not. I can only guess that for some examples, it may be increasing. Why don't you try Gaussian $X$?

Comment: For the Gaussian it's clear since MMSE=$\frac{\sigma^2}{1+\sigma^2}$. So, it's increasing.

Comment: One more thing: the mean of $X$ is assumed to be fixed right?

Comment: Yes. I think we can assume it to be $0$ w.l.o.g.